# Windows "..." directory

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I noticed something weird today. On the windows command prompt these are all valid:

```
cd .....
cd ....
cd ...
```

these are the more well known versions of parent dir and current dir

```
cd ..
cd .
```

What is weird is that other commands fail like `dir .....`.

Why does this happen? Is it the same reason this works: `cd foo\\\\\\bar` (i'm assuming the parser is greedy?)

Comment: `cmd.exe` or PowerShell?

Comment: Perhaps `command.com`? Or Interix or Cygwin shell?

Comment: this was cmd.exe... Despite being marked as "not constructive" I found that in java `new File("....").exists()` always returns true. I suspect that these are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because the programmer that wrote change directory (cd) added that functionality but the directory listing (dir) programmer didn't. The command line is just a collection of little programs. You could maybe ask Raymond Chen about it he writes a [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/) about the evolution of Windows (and sometimes DOS).

Comment: Yea... I'm a reader of Raymond's blog. I suspect that you are correct. Ugg... I hate windows, why this isn't consistent?